# messenger plugin usage in non-mvvmcross environment

Tags: mvvmcross

I had read tutorials on MVVMCross. Came across tutorial using bindings in Non mvvm view models

similar, I was hoping to use the Messenger Plugin (of mvvmcross) as an alternative for Galasoft mvvm light for cross-platform

Is it really mandated that each and every ViewModel should derive from MvxViewModel to take advantage of the messenger Plugin> 
If not, how can we achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really mandated that each and every ViewModel should derive from MvxViewModel to take advantage of the messenger Plugin> If not, how can we achieve it ?

No - there is no such mandate.

The MvvmCross messenger can be used in any class, including viewmodels which do not inherit from `MvxViewModel`

The messenger is just a class - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Messenger/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger/MvxMessengerHub.cs - it has no dependencies on MvxViewModel or any class from Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll